# Can an object automatically delete itself in javascript once it has achieved its purpose?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am wondering if it is possible for an object in javascript to delete itself once it has finished its task.

For example, I have the following object...

```
var myObject = Object.create(baseObject);
myObject.init = function() {
  /* do some stuff... */
   delete this;
};
myObject.init();
```

Does this work?  If not, is there another way?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

That wouldn't work, first because the [`this`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.7) value associated with an execution context is *immutable*.

You might now think that deleting `myObject` (by `delete myObject;`) might work, but that wouldn't do it either.

Variables are really properties of the *Variable Object*, this object is not accessible by code, it is just in front of in the *scope chain*, where you do the variable declarations.

The Variable statement, creates those properties with the `{ DontDelete }` attribute, and that causes the `delete` operator to fail.

An option if you want to achieve this is to *nullify* your `myObject` instance, but that doesn't guarantees that another reference is still pointing to that object.

Recommended lectures:

- [Understanding `delete`](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)
- [Variable instantiation](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.3)

Comment: It appears the bclary.com links are no longer valid. I think these are the fixes: 1) https://bclary.com/2004/11/07/ecma-262.html#a-10.1.7 and 2) https://bclary.com/2004/11/07/ecma-262.html#a-10.1.3

Answer (score 13):

No. `this` is just a local reference to the object so deleting it does not make the object not exist. There is no way for an object to self destruct in this manner. If you have large objects that you believe should be erased afterwards then you should look at using the Facade or Strategy patterns.

Answer (score 6):

You could try

```
window.namespace.myObject = Object.create(baseObject);

namespace.myObject.init = function() {

   /* do some stuff... */

   delete window.namespace.myObject;

}

namespace.myObject.init();
```

Comment: This will not solve the issue, the question was about deleting the object as whole.

Comment: Assuming the only reference to the object is the `namespace.myObject`, then deleting that reference should cause the object to eventually be garbage collected. But, `delete` isn't `dealloc`, as pointed out in the selected answer.

Comment: I'm building a class, GameObject, which should have a method, destroy(). This still doesn't help...

Comment: @SeanValdivia I think it would depend on the nature of what exactly you need to do in a destroy handler. If you're wanting to make it where your `GameObject` can be garbage collected. Essentially, you need to remove all references to that object or have all references go out of scope. So, making sure the object isn't captured in a closure is important. Probably need to look for an article on managing memory in JavaScript.