# Destroy 'this' with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

How do I destroy 'this' within a function so that I destroy the instance of a function from within the function. If this is not possible with pure javascript. Is this possible with prototype? So something like this:

```
this = nil
```

or something like:

```
prototype.destroy(this)
```

I do not know if prototype or javascript has anything like this built-in. Is there a function I can call that will destroy the instance from outside the instance with ease?

Thanks

Comment: can you should a more complete example of your code so that we can understand the "why"?

Comment: And what exactly is `this`, you can't destroy the keyword, but you could probably destroy the reference, depending on what it references. And `nil` <- really ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304860/can-an-object-automatically-delete-itself-in-javascript-once-it-has-achieved-its

Comment: +1 @KevinB for "can you should a more..." while complaining about obvious reasoning, +1 @ adeneo for complaining about "nil" while not understanding what OP obviously means by "this", and +1 @ Mosho for linking to a real answer

Answer (score 3):

You cannot destroy `this` in javascript and even trying to do so runs counter to how things are garbage collected in javascript.  Also, you cannot assign to `this` in javascript.

You do NOT manually free things in javascript.  Instead, you clear all references to an object in javascript and when NO other code has a reference to an object in javascript, THEN and only then will the garbage collector free it.

Since javascript does not allow you to assign to the `this` pointer, when you're in a function that has `this` set to a particular object, you simply can't cause that object to be freed in any way at that moment.  You can make sure that no other objects have a reference to your object and then, when this method finishes, if nothing else has a reference to the object, then it will be freed by the garbage collector.

Memory management in a garbage collected system is completely different than in non-garbage collected languages.  You don't free things yourself.  You clear references to things so that the GC can then clean up those objects at some later time if there are no other references to them.

Here's an example.  Supposed you have this object with a property stored in a global variable:

```
// declare global object and add property to it
var myGlobalObject = {};
myGlobalObject.greeting = "Hello";
```

You don't ever free that global variable explicitly, but if you want the object that it points to to be freed by the garbage collector, then you just clear the reference to the object:

```
myGlobalObject = null;
```

Then, the GC will see that there is no longer any code that has a reference to the object that `myGlobalObject` used to point to and since that object is now unreachable by any code, it will be freed by the GC.