# Javascript object lifecycle

Tags: javascript, multithreading, object

I have a Javascript class like below:

```
var MYCLASS = function(elem, data, op) {

    var options = {};

    var loopForEver = function() {
        console.log('I cant stop me');
        setTimeout(function() {
            loopForEver();
        }, 1000);
    }
    this.init = function() {
        loopForEver();
    }
}
```

when I instantiate the class and call init function, then the loop starts and I get the text in my console every 1 second :

```
var ins = new MYCLASS();
ins.init();
```

Why when I set the instance to null, the thread does not stop? or any time I create a new instance and assign it to the previous instance name, it increases the calls.

in my production code, I do not have infinite loop, but I do have some business logic. do I need to be worried about performance when I create a new instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call setTimeout it is not bound by the function that called it. You need to add a property to object called something like `timeOutID`. As long as the function is still required being used by something like setTimeout it will remain in scope.

```
var MYCLASS = function(elem, data, op) {

    var options = {};
    var timeOutID = null;

    var loopForEver = function() {
        console.log('I cant stop me');
        timeOutID = setTimeout(function() {
            loopForEver();
        }, 1000);
    }
    this.init = function() {
        loopForEver();
    }
    this.stop = function () {
      clearTimeout(timeOutID);
    }
}
```

Comment: But why is the `setTimeout` callback able to execute `loopForEver`, which apparently doesn’t exist anymore? I think, that’s the actual question.

Comment: Because it does exist. As long as the function is still required being used by something like `setTimeout` it will remain in scope. TL;DR Garbage collected languages.

Comment: You might want to put that in the answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have a [memory leak](http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks).

In other words, memory leaks may occur when objects, which are now unreachable, are still kept in memory because they are being referenced somewhere else in the [call stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

Nullifying the instance doesn't clear from memory other references to that object. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2304922/2502532) to "[Can an object automatically delete itself in javascript once it has achieved its purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304860/can-an-object-automatically-delete-itself-in-javascript-once-it-has-achieved-its)"

In fact, your `setTimeout` call is repeatedly creating a new *[execution context](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#execution_context)* each with its own untouchable *[Activation object](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#activation_object_variable_object)*, which are unaffected by assigning the original instance to `null`.

An excerpt from "[Understanding delete](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)" *(Perfection Kills by kangax)* explains it this way:

> When a function is executed, it is said that control enters
>   **execution context**…; that code might call a function, with its own execution context; that function could call another function, and so
>   on and so forth.
>
> Even if function is calling itself recursively, a new execution
>   context is being entered with every invocation.
>
> …when in Function code, a Variable object is … a so-called Activation
>   object. Activation object is created every time execution context for
>   Function code is entered.
>
> Note that Activation object is an internal mechanism and is never
>   really accessible by program code.

**If you want to nullify the instance, you should clean it up first by clearing the timed recursive call using [`.clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout).**