# Set current object to null

Tags: javascript

How do I set the current object to null?

```
function ZPNode(){}; //Constructor 
function _destroy(){ 
    //this = null; --> Won't work obviously 
} 
ZPNode.prototype.remove = function(){ 
    //Remove node 
    _destroy.call(this); 
};
```

Edit: perhaps the description was not clear. What should happen is something like:

```
var tree = ZPTree.create(jsonArr);  
var node = tree.findNode(1); 
node.remove(); 
console.log(node); //null
```

The reason why is simple. You don't want to accidentally do something like:

```
node.remove(); 
node.appendChild(anotherNode); //Oops
```

Possible solution is to work with state on the object if there is no other way.

Edit2: After more research, I don't think that it is possible overall. I'll reluctantly go with a workaround solution. I can do something like:

```
tree.removeNode(node);
```

Although it llooks less clean in my opinion.

Comment: I think you should take a look on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304860/can-an-object-automatically-delete-itself-in-javascript-once-it-has-achieved-its)

Comment: though, it will not remove the object itself. Your function `remove` has no effect

Comment: Why do you want to do so ?

Comment: @Rayon Because when the user removes a node from a tree, it should be set to null. I don't want to force them into node=node.remove();

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is automatically garbage collected; the object's memory will be reclaimed only if the Garbage Collectior decides to run and the object is eligible for that. You don't need to delete *this* inside the *_destroy* function just remove all its references.

```
function ZPNode(){}; //Constructor 
function _destroy(){ 
    //this = null; --> Won't work obviously 
} 
ZPNode.prototype.remove = function(){ 
    //Remove node 
    _destroy.call(this); 
};
```

An option if you want to achieve this is to nullify your Object instance, but that doesn't guarantees that another reference is still pointing to that object.

```
var obj = new ZPNode();
obj = null;
```

Comment: It's more of an api question. When a user calls node.remove(); (which should remove the current node from the tree), the instance should be set to null. I don't want them to force into node = node.remove();

Comment: an example of destroy implementation
function _destroy(){ 
    
 //here you can remove references to other objects  references
   delete this.element;
 //remove elements from dom   
 this.elementNodeReference.remove();  
 //delete global references
 delete window.ZPNodeTree; // window.ZPNodeTree = null; 
 
}

Comment: Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I found the most logical solution for my specific use case.
It was as simple as to set the reference to the current tree to 0.

```
this._treeId = 0;
```

It doesn't actually matter that the node continues to exist, since it wasn't connected to the tree anymore.
Even more, it would make sense to keep the node in existence, as it may be re-appended later to another node that is still connected to the tree.

Thanks for help.